# ng-controller calling twice when ng-click=function() in dropddown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a simple dropdown. When I am click on dropdown menu a function in page is called twice and hence controller is also calling twice.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="dropdown col-md-3">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{selectName}}
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="searchDealer in searchDealers">
            <!--<a ui-sref="app.dashboard.v1.summary({searchId: searchDealer.siteId?searchDealer.siteId:0, startDate: (startDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'), endDate: (endDate| date: 'MM/dd/yyyy')})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ng-click="change(searchDealer)">-->
            <a ng-click="loadNewUrl();">
                {{searchDealer.dealerName}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
$scope.loadNewUrl = function () {
    if ($scope.getCurrentPage() === "dashboard") {
        $state.go("app.dashboard.v1." + $scope.getCurrentTab(), {searchId: ($stateParams.searchId ? $stateParams.searchId : 0), startDate: $('#startDate').val(), endDate: $('#endDate').val()});
    } else if ($scope.getCurrentPage() === "report") {

        $state.go("app.report.reports", {searchId: ($stateParams.searchId ? $stateParams.searchId : 0), startDate: $('#startDate').val(), endDate: $('#endDate').val()});
    } else if ($scope.getCurrentPage() === "dealer") {
        $state.go("app.admin.dealer", {searchId: ($stateParams.searchId ? $stateParams.searchId : 0), startDate: $('#startDate').val(), endDate: $('#endDate').val()});
    } else if ($scope.getCurrentPage() === "conversion") {
        $state.go("app.conversion.conversion", {searchId: ($stateParams.searchId ? $stateParams.searchId : 0), startDate: $('#startDate').val(), endDate: $('#endDate').val()});
    } else {
        $location.path("/" + "?startDate=" + $('#startDate').val() + "&endDate=" + $('#endDate').val());
    }
};
$scope.getCurrentPage = function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf("dealer") > 0) {
        return "dealer";
    }
    if (url.indexOf("report") > 0) {
        return "report";
    }
    if (url.indexOf("conversion") > 0) {
        return "conversion";
    }
    return "dashboard";
};
$scope.getCurrentTab = function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf("url") > 0) {
        return "url";
    }
    if (url.indexOf("media") > 0) {
        return "media";
    }
    return "summary";
};
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: The function does the page load hence either by state.go or location.path thats why controller gets reload. if you don't want to reload controller then In your $routeProvider definition, while defining the route, specify the option reloadOnSearch to false

Comment: Hi, Thankyou,but we are not using $routeProvider. When mulitple params calling the page only the page is loading twice..if we remove startdate and enddate the page is calling once, but data is not passing.on other case if we add the params then page is calling twice ...see the code : state("app.report.reports", {url:"/reports/:searchId?startDate/:endDate", templateUrl:"views/reports/report.html", resolve:i(["app.report.report"],["d3Bar","d3-pieChart",'dashboardCss'])})

Comment: Maybe you should use button or div instead of <a>. Not sure if that's the case. I have a feeling that <a> has some magic with empty href that makes it call twice.

Comment: snippet you provided will not fire the function twice. Maybe you included AngularJS twice, check if the function will be call twice use console.log for debugging.

Comment: check if you have used ng-controller twice in the same view?